# how to handle extreme hug Weblogic server .out file?

Tags: weblogic, log-rotation

Weblogic server under logs folder has `servername.out0000x` files which are extreme huge. Log folder is over 1.4TB and some `servername.out000` files are over 100 G. 
How these file can be reduced size or can be deleted? 
Is there any way to handle these `servername.out` files?

Comment: I've found a [similar howto](https://pitss.com/us/2013/11/15/log-rotation-for-weblogic-forms-and-reports-11g/) via google

Comment: @djdomi, thanks for your help. let me try it out, first. But it is about ```.log``` files, which is 500MB. My issue is ```.out.000x```. Mine are currently  over 100G now.

Comment: are these just logs?

Comment: if those logs are standard output and not server logs just use logrotate from your OS, it is weblogic defined server logs you can adjust their rotation and size from the weblogic console